# regex to find characters in a String

Tags: regex

I have a strings like  ***`1 - Copy (2)`*** ***`2 - Copy (2)`*** ***`3 - Copy (2)`***. Here I want replace string which contains ***`Copy (2)`*** with string ***`demo`***.

- > ***`1 - Copy (2)`***  to ***`demo`***
- > ***`2 - Copy (2)`***  to ***`demo`***
- > ***`3 - Copy (2)`***  to ***`demo`***

I tried like `^.*Copy (2).*$`
but it is not working.

Comment: You may want to escape the parenthesis and capture Copy + Space: `^.*(Copy \(2\)).*$`

Comment: It is working. Thanks

Comment: `^.*Copy \(2\).*$` make sure you've the multiline flag enabled to recognise `^` and `$`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parenthesis: `.*Copy\ \(2\).*`